# Add Icon dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Using Javascript to Add element to the div tag**

```
div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td><div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label="<i class=fa fa-check></i>" data-off-label="<i class=fa fa-times></i>"><input type="checkbox" id="user'+varresult.Id+'" data-toggle="switch" /></div></td>';
```

**div_appuser** is variable.

Shows error in Developer console.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

**How to Add Font awesome icon as data-on-label on bootstrap switch ?**
Code :

```
document.getElementById('div_appuser').innerHTML='';
                            div_appuser='<table class="table table-hover table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Username</th><th>UserType</th><th>Email</th><th>Allow</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
                            for(var i=0;i<resultofusers.length;i++)
                            {
                                div_appuser=div_appuser+'<tr>';
                                var varresult = resultofusers[i];
                                div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td>'+(i+1)+'</td>';                                    
                                if(varresult.Name!=undefined)
                                {
                                    div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td>'+varresult.Name+'</td>';
                                }
                                if(varresult.Username!=undefined)
                                {
                                    div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td>'+varresult.Username+'</td>';
                                }
                                if(varresult.UserType!=undefined)
                                {
                                    div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td>'+varresult.UserType+'</td>';
                                }                                    
                                if(varresult.Email!=undefined)
                                {
                                    div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td>'+varresult.Email+'</td>';
                                }
                                if(i<resultofactiveusers.length)
                                {
                                     for(var k=0;k<resultofactiveusers.length;k++)
                                        {
                                            //alert(resultofactiveusers[k]);
                                            if(resultofactiveusers[k].MBT_SFFB__ApplicationUserName__c==varresult.Id)
                                            {
                                                if(resultofactiveusers[i].MBT_SFFB__Validated__c==true)
                                                {
                                                    div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td><div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label="<i class=fa fa-check></i>" data-off-label="<i class=fa fa-times></i>"><input type="checkbox" id="user'+varresult.Id+'" checked="" data-toggle="switch" /></div></td>';                                            
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td><div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label="<i class=fa fa-check></i>" data-off-label="<i class=fa fa-times></i>"><input type="checkbox" id="user'+varresult.Id+'" data-toggle="switch" /></div></td>';                                        
                                                }
                                            }

                                        }   
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    div_appuser=div_appuser+'<td><div class="switch switch-square" data-on-label="<i class=fa fa-check></i>" data-off-label="<i class=fa fa-times></i>"><input type="checkbox" id="user'+varresult.Id+'" data-toggle="switch" /></div></td>';
                                }

                                div_appuser=div_appuser+'</tr>';
                            }
                            document.getElementById('div_appuser').innerHTML=div_appuser+'</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: show us your code..

Comment: data-on-label="<i class=fa fa-check></i>" Is valid or need to write data-on-label="<i class="fa fa-check"></i>"

Comment: Please add your code to your question, and also try to explain what you want,

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with your html string which you store in div_appuser variable.

Try storing varresult.Id in one variable before you assign and use that variable while appending. This will remove SyntaxError: Unexpected string .
I dont know what is the issue with font awesome, so you need to debug it after solving syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `bootstrapSwitch();` function after rendring your switches dynamically like

```
$('.switch').bootstrapSwitch();
```

or

```
$('.switch').bootstrapSwitch('state', !data, true);
```